# grails g:select tag

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using a g:select tag like this:

```
<td><g:select name="newCity"
        id="${'newCity_' +cityData.uid}"
        from="${cityData.name}"
        value="${cityData.someValue}"
        noSelection="${['null':'Select City...']}" class="newCity" />
</td>
```

which renders the following HTML:

```
<td>
<select name="newCity" id="newCity_abc" class="newCity" >
<option value="null">Select City...</option>
<option value="A" >A</option>
<option value="B" >B</option>
<option value="C" >C-</option>
<option value="D" >D</option>
</select>
</td>
```

However, I want my HTML to look like this; with class inserted since I am doing some javascript validation:

```
<td>
<select name="newCity" id="newCity_abc" class="newCity" >
<option value="null">Select City...</option>
<option value="A" class="populated" >A</option>
<option value="B" class="notpopulated" >B</option>
<option value="C" class="populated" >C</option>
<option value="D" class="notpopulated" >D</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Is this possible?

Do I need to create a custom tag library to acheive this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  The [select tag implementation](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L683) (which [writes out the `<option>` tags](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L728)) calls the [private method `writeValueAndCheckIfSelected`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy#L801) to fill in the `option`, and this is not aware of any class names.

There is a 2 year old [New Feature Request on the Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3951), but I think you may be stuck rolling your own tag to do this for your specific situation.

Comment: tim, any pointers on how to go about writing my own tag? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do `grails create-tag-lib` then basically copy the existing select tag implementation into your tag, but add the classes in for the options.  ie; this guy wanted to add optgroup to select: http://vivin.net/2009/02/11/creating-a-custom-select-tag-with-optgroup-in-grails/

Comment: is there a way to do this by delegating to the Grails tag, rather than copy-pasting the source?

Comment: may be at the time document.ready (of jquery), you can add class name to specific select tag, by using it's id. If you don't want to create you our tag lib.

Comment: @Don not that I can think of, due to the private nature of `writeValueAndCheckIfSelected`...  I may be wrong though.  @Nirmal writing a JS function may well be the easiest solution to this problem, so options would be decorated at `document.ready` time as you say