# Grails Select tag: adding styles to specific opitions

Tags: grails, select, groovy, drop-down-menu

Hi I am trying to make a dynamically created drop down list in grails that emphasizes only certain option tags. Here is what I have:

```
<g:select class="DropDownList"
    from="${listOfMaps}" 
    optionValue="${{(it.match=='Something'?'<em>':'') + it.thingToPrint
    + (it.match=='Something'?'</em>':'') }}" 
    />
```

and this works in the sense that it will print the thing to print, but when it is suppose to add the `<em>` tag it prints it like this:

```
<option>&lt;em&gt;ITEM&lt;/em&gt;</option>
```

And that is not what I need. that prints `<em>ITEM</em>` in the drop down list.

Does anyone know how to get it to be this instead:

```
<option><em>ITEM</em></option>
```

so that it will print '*ITEM*' ?

The resources that I have used thus far:

- http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Tags/select.html
- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2988

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976941/grails-gselect-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<g:select/>` tag html encodes values returned from the optionValue attribute, that is why your html is getting escaped.

The best way to do this is to write a custom taglib, however, even then you'll probably want to do this with CSs instead of markup since CSS styling of an `<option>` tag is probably more broadly supported.

Comment: So is there any way to create an id tag for each `<option>` tag? That way I could write a javascript function to change the styles.

Comment: Not through the provided `<g:select/>` tag. The built-in taglibs are designed for simple use cases and most of the time require you to write your own implementation to get the behavior you're looking for. I'd say about half the time I end up writing my own markup.